# Why CPack generates an empty package?

Tags: cmake, installation, packaging, cpack

There are exists one cmake project that creates one console application.
I add the ability of package generation to that cmake project:

```
# ... above cmake code for one console application creation
# below code that I add:

#install
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION "C:/Apps/Consolas" COMPONENT applications)

# pack
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "MyOrg")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "CPack Component Installation Example")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0.0")

set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")

include(CPack)
```

The package creation passes without any errors, (!) but the package is empty.

Why it happens and how to fix this issue? (I used cmake 3.12.0)

Comment: You are not adding the component to your package, i.e. `cpack_add_component(applications DISPLAY_NAME "Apps" DESCRIPTION "describe whats in the package")`

Comment: @vre, Before last line "include(CPack)" I include two lines: "include(CPackComponent)" and as you wrote "cpack_add_component(applications DISPLAY_NAME "Apps" DESCRIPTION "describe whats in the package")". The package generation passes without any errors, but package still empty :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DESTINATION` should be a relative directory within the package.

Consider the following instead:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin" COMPONENT applications)
```

Explanation: CPack will create the ZIP file after installing the project into a subdirectory of `<build-dir>/_CPack_Packages`. By specifying an absolute path, no file will be installed in the expected subdirectory and the package will be empty.